# How do I list supported Elliptic Curves in python

Tags: python, openssl, elliptic-curve

I am trying to create a python script which lists the supported curves. Basically I want to do this in Python

`openssl ecparam -list_curves`

**EDIT:**

I've tried the pyOpenSSL wrapper module which does contain a with similar functionality but I am hoping for a simpler way to do this without the use of this module

Comment: well I have been looking into different open source libraries on git but they mostly contain the implementation of the Crypto algorithm where they have already chosen the curves. I just want a script that simply list the curves supported

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I improved your topic.  What is missing is what you have tried so far.  Instead of replying in a comment, it would be better if you edited your post and included it in as part of the question.  Just prefix it by **EDIT** so others know what you have edited.

Comment: python doesn't support any elliptic curves out of the box. The only crypto it contains are hash functions and hmacs.